# What is the affinization of M_g?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

This question is inspired by [What is an example of a function on M_g?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453/what-is-an-example-of-a-function-on-mg) . Consider M<sub>g</sub>, the moduli space of genus g curves, NOT compactified. When g is 3 or greater, this is not affine. Does anyone know a good description of the ring of global functions on M<sub>g</sub>, or of the spectrum of this ring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By exercise 2.10 of *Moduli of Curves* by Harris and Morrison there exists a complete curve through any two points of M_g (this follows from the fact that the `boundary of the Hodge theory' compactification of M_g has codimension at least 2 and that M_g is quasi-projective). It follows the only global functions on M_g are constant.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't M_g have codimension 2 in the Satake compactification for g > 2?