# Regular (or complex analytic) functions on M_3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

Let $M_3$ be the moduli space of genus three curves over $\mathbb C$. 
Are there non-constant regular functions of this space? What about complex analytic functions?

This question is prompted by the following one :
[Does the moduli space of genus three curves contain a complete genus two curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111556/does-the-moduli-space-of-genus-three-curves-contain-a-complete-genus-two-curve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an older MO post addressing this question (which appears to apply to M_3, though I don't have Harris-Morrison handy):
[What is the affinization of M_g?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/559/what-is-the-affinization-of-mg/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Harris Morrison says indeed that if you take Satake compaction $\tilde M_g$ of $M_g$ then first of all it is projective and second $\tilde M_g\setminus M_g$ has codimension $2$ provided $g\ge 3$ (a bit surpising :)) . So there are plenty of curves on $\tilde M_g$ that miss $\tilde M_g\setminus M_g$.